# Converting MSAL Access Token to Hapi JWT token

Tags: vue.js, hapi.js, azure-ad-msal

We're trying to work out how to consume an MSAL access token from a front-end vue.js application on our hapi.js back-end.

Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-call-api) for *Single Page Applications* we are successfully adding the MSAL accessToken to our *http* requests as a Bearer token. This token can be seen on the back-end if we disable JWT on the API server.

How do we validate the MSAL access token so that we can return a valid JWT token?
(secondary question is what is the recommended auth strategy for the login route?)

Comment: Get a token with msal and then use Microsoft's node passport [library](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) for validating access tokens.  Specifically, the bearer strategy.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer.

I had managed to find that the accessToken is a valid JWT and can be decoded by the backend. However I am more comfortable knowing there is a strategy out there that can confirm that the Token hasn't been spoofed.